# Sum calculations in Stata

Tags: stata

I have problems with managing data in stata and moreover I tried to search but maybe my search questions are incorrect. So I m very sorry if the question already existed. 
if to look to the pic you will see, that I should calculate countries. Sum of the same countries by every id. I have a huge dataset, so I need to do it fast and not to loose time.
ask me questions[stata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7zOD.jpg)

Comment: You got help, which is good, but for any future questions please note that specific questions explaining your Stata dataset and illustrated with Stata code you tried are expected under this tag.  You posted a picture of an Excel worksheet, I think (it's barely readable), which is about as relevant as posting a picture of a boat while asking questions about cars. The downvotes signal dissatisfaction with the question, not personal hostility. Your urgency (we've all been there too) is not a factor.

Comment: @Nick Cox thanks for you comment. For the next time will not do the same mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you have in mind, but it sounds like you want:

```
bysort id country: generate count = _N
```

If not, a clearer example with fewer countries would be helpful.

Comment: this is not what I need. this command I know but its calculate every country_code and make total sum. For example there are 22 id (written like 1 1 1 ) but they are from different countries. Some country_codes can be repeated. What I need is to calculate the sum of every country. For example if with id ==2 there are two countries Belgium and one is USA in the new collum should be Belgium -2, US -1. Is it more clear now?

Comment: is it possible to send an example in stata somewhere? I see that I can add only pics there

Comment: i added pic , can you see it?

Comment: @PollyShevchuk, how about adding the country variable to the `varlist` following `bysort`? i.e. `bysort id country: ...`